# Write column as date with format Java-Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm using Java-Spark.

I have the following table in `Dataset` object:

```
      creationDate
  15/06/2018 09:15:28
```

I make select to this column

```
Dataset<Row> ds = dataframe.select(new Column("creationDate").as("mydate").cast("date"));
```

And I write it with:

```
ds.write().mode(mode).save(hdfsDirectory);
```

Try also:

```
ds.write().option("dateFormat","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").mode(mode).save(hdfsDirectory);
```

But When I'm looking on my table the column `mydate` is null.

How can I write my date into my Hive table? I know the default date format should be dd-MM-yyyy but my text is with dd/MM/yyyy format and I can't change it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: try converting the date format and casting for that column. cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(creationdate,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') as date)

Comment: How can I do it?